# Can't run the package EmguCV due to the incompatibility of the package ZedGraph

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I want to use **Emgu** on my Xamarin multiplateform project, but I can't due to **ZedGraph** incompatbility.

I am working on **Visual Studio 2019**, with **Emgu.CV (4.0.1.3373)** and **ZedGraph (5.1.7)**. I installed **Emgu.CV** with NuGet package manager and it needs **ZedGraph** to work.

After installation, I get the following error (translated) :

```
NU1202 : Package ZedGraph 5.1.7 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package ZedGraph 5.1.7 supports : net35-client (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Client)
```

And on the solution explorer *Solution > Dependencies > NuGet > EMGU.CV (4.0.1.3373) > ZedGraph (5.1.7)*, I have the following warning ;

```
Package 'ZedGraph 5.1.7' was restored using '.NetFramework, Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard, Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I have seen here : http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18145 that I need the commercial license of Visual Studio in order to install Emgu.Util with Emgu.CV to run it.

Do I realy need to buy the license or there is a way to fix this issue ?

Edit : Its the license of Emgu, not Visual Studio

Comment: ZedGraph doesn't seem to support multiplatform project. It supports .Net Framework which is only for Windows application. You are dependent on .NetStandard which is for multiplatform. You need to figure out the right version for ZedGraph that supports .NetStandard. If they don't support, you need to figure out an alternative

Comment: Therefore, I need to get a good version of ZedGraph ? And if I can't find one, I have to buy Emgu full version in order to make ZedGraph work ?

Comment: Did you try the 6.0.0-aplha version? It says it supports .Net Standard 2.0. Check it out. It might be worth a try.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZedGraph/6.0.0-alpha0001

Comment: I've tried it after your anwser, but Emgu only uses the ZedGraph 5.1.7 version.

Comment: Then its not likely you can solve this. Emgu doesnt support .NetCore currently. It doesn't depend on licence. You can still use the open source licence if you dont get monetary benefit by using their product.Unless they support you cant use them. Either you switch to .Net Framework/ You choose an alternative for Emgu.CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Carbine.

The commercial license is actualy required.